# Set content with plain text does not work in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I tried this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent("<b>This</b> is <u>my</u> first example.", {format: 'text'});
```

But still, It was typed as an HTML content. I did not find the error.

Answer (score 0):

You missed ".selection":

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent("<b>This</b> is <u>my</u> first example.", {format: 'text'});
```